# Eclipse method header error

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, header

I'm having trouble creating the most simple of methods in eclipse, I keep getting an error on the line that the method header is declared it looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuU31.jpg)(error information is in the console) This is just the code that i have to have written for the error to pop-up.) I haven't written code since before winter break so I don't know if I may have messed up my jdk or jre, but in all my past projects the methods work as they should and there are no errors, even if I create a new method.

edit: thanks dimoniy, it's been a long winter.

Comment: Include the code in your post so that if your link is no longer valid, the code is still available to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare methods within other methods. Just move your method out of the `main()`